# CORS error on POST (Lambda server, React client)

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, cors, fetch-api

I've had a working cors config to GET from the server. Changing the parameters for a POST is giving the below errors

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at https://... (Reason: CORS preflight response
> did not succeed). Status code: 422.
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at https://... (Reason: CORS request did not
> succeed). Status code: (null).

These are the params I'm using on the client and server side.

```
//React(fetch):
const fetch_params = {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: "cors", //Doesn't seem to be needed for the GET
      body: JSON.stringify(fetch_body),
      headers: new Headers({
        "Content-Type": 'application/json'
      })
    }

//Lambda(Node):
response_headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": event.headers.origin, //Essentially returns the same origin as received
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
        }
```

The above config worked for GETs even when I was running the react app on localhost. But it's now giving errors when for POSTs even if the app is hosted on aws-amplify with https.

(The amplify and lambda are on different VPCs(?) and can't be run in the same one for now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was, when an OPTIONS request was made, my code just saw the empty params in the body/path and returned a 422 error.

The code itself sent back a verbose error message, but browsers interpreted the 422 error as a CORS issue and hid the error message.

After hardcoding a response code of 200, I got to see the error message and found a solution:

```
if(event.requestContext.http.method == "OPTIONS")
{
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": event.headers.origin,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
        },
        body: "Processed Successfully"
    };

    return response;
}
```

The above responds correctly to an OPTIONS request, so the following POST can continue normally.